# General strategies solving non linear congruence

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to complete a nice summary for solving non-linear modular equations as i couldn't find a good one. I mean the specific (but still very wide) case of the form $f(x)\equiv0 \mod m$ where $f(x)$ is a polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}.$
The problem is clearly reduced to the form $m = p^k$ where p is prime, as we can conclude results for any composite number $n = p_{1}^{k_{1}}\cdot p_{2}^{k_{2}}\cdots p_{t}^{k_{t}}$ using the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

More specifically, i am trying to divide all possibilities of polynomials into general cases where all the elements in a specific general case are answered the same to the following questions:

1) Is it possible to determine if there is a solution or not?

2) Is it possible to determine the number of solutions?

3) Is it possible to find the solutions?

Where in "possible" i mean all kinds of ways except trying every possible number.

Partial answers are very welcome.

Thanks

EDIT:

Assume we have the polynomial factorized over the real numbers field, if $k=1$ all three questions are trivial. so the question is for $k>1$.

So we have $f(x) = (x-\alpha_{1})\cdots(x-\alpha_{n})$ where $\alpha_{1},\dots,\alpha_{n} \in  \mathbb{R}$.

So clearly we have the solutions $\{\alpha_{i} : \alpha_{i} \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

I have managed to reduce this problem in the case where $\alpha_{1},\dots,\alpha_{n} \in  \mathbb{Z}$ to finding roots over $\mathbb{R}$ as follows:

there exists $\beta_{1},\dots,\beta_{n} \in \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(x) \equiv (x+\beta_{1})\cdots(x+\beta_{n}) \mod m$ hence:

$f(x) \equiv 0 \mod m$ iff

$(x+\beta_{1})\cdots(x+\beta_{n}) = 0$ or

$(x+\beta_{1})\cdots(x+\beta_{n}) = m$ or

$(x+\beta_{1})\cdots(x+\beta_{n}) = 2m$ or

$\dots$ or

$(x+\beta_{1})\cdots(x+\beta_{n}) = (m-3)m$

So in this case, assuming we can factorize the polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$, all the questions are answered positively.

Is there a better way to deal with this? and what about the case where $\alpha_{1},\dots,\alpha_{n} \in \mathbb{R}$?

Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp%27s_algorithm may get you started.

Comment: Have you had a look at that link?

Comment: Thank you, yes I have. I get the feeling that the part of factorizing polynomials was widely discussed and therefore I am mainly interested in solving in a post factorization state and mainly for k>1 where the number of distinct solutions modulo m can be larger than the degree of the polynomial. I did reduce this question into a relatively simple state but is still a lot of work and can be done in general only for degree smaller or equal to 4, and I'm quite sure there are better reductions. Will be glad for any help on this topic.

Comment: "solving a post factorization state" You have reduced the problem to finding solutions modulo a prime power; if you have factored the polynomial modulo the prime power, then the linear factors tell you what you need to know about the solutions. Maybe if you go into some more detail on what you have been able to do and where exactly you get stuck then it would be possible for someone to help you.

Comment: OK edited my progression and new goals. Thanks.